# Motivation for this partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the significance of the following PDE?

$$u_t -\Delta u + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+|x|^2} u_{x_i} =f(x) \text{ in }\Omega\times(0,1]\, ?$$

I have this in my assignment, and have to solve some bound, but I have no idea how to think about this $\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$ term.

Is this PDE in the literature, or does someone know of some motivation for it?

---

I should say something about what I am thinking, says the help centre.

I see a heat equation with an extra term. Should I think that $f(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+|x|^2} u_{x_i}$?

Comment: Read Convection–diffusion equation [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection–diffusion_equation).

Comment: The "motivation" for an exam subject can simply be that it is a feasible subject...

Comment: @JeanMarie That wasn't what I was intending to imply (that I am asking "Why do we care?"). I am not looking for motivation to work on it, I am simply thinking understanding what sort of world this problem would live in, would allow me to find texts that are relevant - and would allow me to appreciate what we are going for.

Thinking of $\frac{1}{1+\|x\|^2}$ makes me think that we are scaling inversely as we move from the origin in $n$-dimensional space as some physical problem, but I haven't thought enough about it.

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks, I will try to reconcile these two concepts.